# How to get the value from the before selected radio?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my case I have lines of radioboxes, every radio has a value. This value must be calculated and the result must be placed in a DIV.

My Problem is, I can't find a way to subtract the value of the choosen radion before. 
let me show you a sample markup:

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="tools" value="20" type="radio"></td>
        <td><input name="tools" value="300" type="radio"></td>
        <td><input name="tools" value="1000" type="radio"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><input name="addons" value="5" type="radio"></td>
       <td><input name="addons" value="10" type="radio"></td>
     </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JavaScript :

```
var radioClick   = $('input[type="radio"]');

radioClick.on('change', function(evt){

      // function sub or add the price... 
      // here is a shortcut of the add calc version...
      var price = $(this).val(),
      showPrice = $('#result').text(),
      endresult = parseFloat(showPrice) + parseFloat(price),
      $('#result').text(endResult);
});
```

With checkboxes it works fine, but in case of radioboyes I don't have a click-event to identify this on I must subtract.

in the first line we see the radios `name=tools`. here I take at first this one with value 20.
after that the value 20 will be shown in the`#result`, fine. But when I take now another radio `name=tools` the new value will add to the 20. and that is my problem. I don't know how to find the before selected radio button to get this value and subtract it.

Comment: If you want to subtract the value that's already there, why add it in the first place? Just overwrite the text field with the new value. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're after but don't do this 'endresult = parseFloat(showPrice) + parseFloat(price)' do 'endresult = parseFloat(price)'

Comment: First I select radio with value 20 and 20 will be displayed in result. Then I select radio with value 300. What should happen at this point? What do you want to display in result? 300+20 or 300-20 or 300?

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:
html code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="tools" class="test1" value="20" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input name="tools" class="test1" value="300" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input name="tools" class="test1" value="1000" type="radio"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input name="addons" class="test" value="5" type="radio"></td>
   <td><input name="addons" class ="test" value="10" type="radio"></td>
 </tr>
```

javascript:

```
<script>

var testPrice  = 0;
var test1Price = 0;
var endprice = 0;
var price ='';
 $('.test').click(function(){
 price = $(this).val();
 testPrice = price;
 endPrice = parseFloat(testPrice) + parseFloat(test1Price),

  $('#result').text(endPrice);
 });
 $('.test1').click(function(){
 var price = $(this).val();
  test1Price = price;
   endPrice = parseFloat(testPrice) + parseFloat(test1Price),
  $('#result').text(endPrice);
  });


   </script>
```

try it's demo on http://jsfiddle.net/rxrzX/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to substract. You can just find 2 value of 2 diff radio button : `tools` and `addons`. Then just add them and write in the `div`

You can get radio button value by  :

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked').val();
```

I think try this :

```
var radioClick   = $('input[type="radio"]');

radioClick.on('change', function(evt){
      // function sub or add the price... 
      // here is a shortcut of the add calc version...
      var toolsprice = $('input[name=tools]:checked').val(),
      var addonsprice = $('input[name=addons]:checked').val(),
      endresult = parseFloat(toolsPrice) + parseFloat(addonsprice),
      $('#result').text(endResult);
});
```

Comment: Nope it doesnt work, and i have more than these two <tr>. you click one radio, it doesnt matter which name it have, and the value must be calc with the given term in #result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object literal that tracks the value, using a closure:

```
radioClick.on('change', (function()
{
    var valTracker = {},
    resultDiv = $('#result');//easier on the DOM
    return function(evt)
    {
        valTracker[this.name] = valTracker[this.name] || 0;//get old value
        var endResult = parseFloat(resultDiv.text()) + parseFloat($(this).val()) - valTracker[this.name];//subtract old value, too
        valTracker[this.name] = parseFloat($(this).val());//set current value
        resultDiv.text(endResult);
    }
}()));
```

The `valTracker` object literal tracks the current radio value (the name of the element is used as property). I've also kept a reference to the `$('#result')` div in the closure. That way, you don't have to query the DOM every time the callback function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code below: <kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arulmr/kcwuX/)**</kbd>

```
var radio_groups = []
$(":radio").each(function(){
    if (radio_groups.indexOf(this.name) == -1){
        radio_groups.push(this.name);
    }
});

$('input:radio').change(function(evt){
    var resultPrice = 0;
    $.each(radio_groups, function(){
        curPrice = $(':radio[name="' + this + '"]:checked').val();
        if (!(curPrice)){
            curPrice = 0;
        }
        resultPrice = parseInt(resultPrice) + parseInt(curPrice);
    });
    $('#result').text(resultPrice);
});
```

This will work, even if you add more radio button groups. If you want this functionality only for specific groups, define the names in the array `radio_groups` instead of getting them from the document.